# facebook android sdk - can't decode profile picture from json response

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I was playing with facebook android sdk. Till yesterday their sample Hackbook example code was working. But today it is not working any more. I looked into the json response and it seems like facebook changed their json response format.

This is the response for request field of `"name, picture"`:

```
{"name":"Mohammad Haque","id":"xxxxxxxx","picture":{"data":
{"url":"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-ash3\/xxxx.jpg","is_silhouette":false}}}
```

It looks like profile url now wrapped inside another parent item. Has anyone faced this problem? I could not find any relevant information on facebook.

Thanks

Comment: That change has been announced for quite a long time now, as part of the October 3rd migration – https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#october-2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Facebook updates http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

According to Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) - picture returns string; If the **"October 2012 Breaking Changes"** migration setting is enabled for your app, this field will be an object with the url and is_silhouette fields; is_silhouette is true if the user has not uploaded a profile picture

I retrieved picture url by this query:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large

Answer (score 1):

```
         JSONObject jb=Util.parseJson(query);       
         JSONArray ja=jb.optJSONArray("picture")
         JSONArray v=ja.optJSONArray("data")
         JSONObject j=v.optJSONObject(0);
         j.get("name").toString();
         j.get("url").toString();
```

Comment: I used short version within try/catch block: Thanks btw. json.getJsonObject("picture").getJsonObject("data").getString("url");

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the JSON appropiately with the changes and it should work.